# Using Ajax, Jquery inserting data in database in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net

![enter image description here][1]In asp.net, I am trying to insert data using Ajax, Jquery but I am not getting insert data in database, when I place break point at a method but compiler is not coming at break point. Please help me, I am placing the code.

```
  <script type ="text/javascript" >

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btns').click(function () {

        var firstname = $('#<%= txtFirstname.ClientID %>').val();
            var phonenumber = $('#<%= txtphonenumber.ClientID %>').val();
            var orgtype = $('#<%= ddlOrgatype.ClientID %>').text();
            var orgisaname = $('#<%= txtorganame.ClientID %>').val();
            var orgnisemail = $('#<%= txtorgemail.ClientID %>').val();
            var stateid = $('#<%= ddlstate.ClientID %>').val();
            var districtid = $('#<%= ddlDistrict.ClientID %>').val();
            var location = $('#<%= txtlocatio.ClientID %>').val();
            var userid = $('#<%= txtusername.ClientID %>').val()
            var password = $('#<%= txtpassword.ClientID %>').val();
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Registrationpage.aspx/InsertData",
                data: "{'firstname':'" + firstname + "','phonenumber':'" + phonenumber + "','Organitype':'" + orgtype + "','OrgnaisaName':'" + orgisaname + "','OrgnaisaEmail':'" + orgnisemail + "','Stateid':'" + stateid + "','Districtid':'" + districtid + "','Location':'" + location + "','Userid':'" + userid + "','passowrd':'" + password + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    alert('Inserted');
                    $('#dvreslt').html = "Inserted Successfully";

                } ,  
                error: function (data) { alert(Error) }
            });

        });
    });
```

//////////

```
     [WebMethod]
    protected static string InsertData(string firstname, string phonenumber, string Organitype, string OrgnaisaName, string OrgnaisaEmail, string Stateid, string Districtid, string Location, string Userid, string passowrd)
    {
        IBusinessLogic iBusinessLogic = BLFactory.GetBLObject(BLObjectType.Register);
        BusinessService businessService = new BusinessService();  
        RegisterDO objRegisterDO = new RegisterDO();
        objRegisterDO.UserName = firstname; objRegisterDO.MobileNo = phonenumber; objRegisterDO.organisationType = Organitype;
        objRegisterDO.OrganisationName = OrgnaisaName; objRegisterDO.OrganisationEmail = OrgnaisaEmail; objRegisterDO.StateID = Convert.ToInt32(Stateid);
        objRegisterDO.Distictid = Convert.ToInt32(Districtid); objRegisterDO.Location = Location; objRegisterDO.UserID = Userid; objRegisterDO.Password = passowrd;

        businessService.BusinessLogic = iBusinessLogic;
        if (businessService.Execute(OperationType.Create, objRegisterDO))
        {
            return "inserted";
        }
        else
            return "fasle";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I correct your data in request. It passing how javascript object

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Registrationpage.aspx/InsertData",
    data: { firstname: firstname, phonenumber: phonenumber, 
            Organitype: orgtype, OrgnaisaName: orgisaname, 
            OrgnaisaEmail: orgnisemail, 
            Stateid: stateid, Districtid: districtid, 
            Location: location, 
            Userid: userid, passowrd: password }
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

        alert('Inserted');
        $('#dvreslt').html = "Inserted Successfully";

    } ,  
    error: function (response) { alert('Error') }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is still throwing error, it is not going to web method where I put break point. Error message is "native code", at error: function

Comment: hi, igor semin, I place alert(Error) in error: function(data) where I am getting the message "native code".

Comment: check response for errors, and you can't use Error as parameter - it's no defined

Comment: k, I will check and inform you

Comment: it is showing just error no error message is displaying

Comment: what is in response? what is happened in server code?